# Print only selected item from drop down

Tags: javascript, html

I have a select input on my page. When I print the page all the options of select get printed instead of the one that is selected. How do I make it so that only the option selected is printed?

```
    <select class="form-control" id=myID onchange="update_status(this)">
        <option value="1" selected>Pending</option>
        <option value="2">Under-Preparation</option>
        <option value="3">Delivered</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: It looks fine can you recreate the problem in a jsfiddle?

Comment: I used print in my browser to generate a PDF of the page and it looks fine to me. [See screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/YWSWfG1.png)

Answer (score 1):

Print the selected choice's value like following snippet. Run code snippet for demonstration.

```js
function update_status(selected_option){
  console.log(selected_option.value);
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control" id=myID onchange="update_status(this)">
        <option value="s1" selected>Pending</option>
        <option value="s2">Under-Preparation</option>
        <option value="s3">Delivered</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine...

javascript print() funtion just shows the rendered[visible] items in pdf preview.

[Here is example you can visualize.](https://jsfiddle.net/rietykity/j8j56hsr/)

```
This might helps. Have fun.
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done as below-

```
function update_status(currentObj){
console.log(currentObj.options[currentObj.selectedIndex].value);
}
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/manishghec/rzhngk07/)

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Add a **this.value** instead **this**, checkout the snippet.

```js
function update_status(vm) {
  console.log(vm);
  }
```

```html
<select class="form-control" id=myID onchange="update_status(this.value)">
        <option value="1" selected>Pending</option>
        <option value="2">Under-Preparation</option>
        <option value="3">Delivered</option>
    </select>
```